# mysql query two tables with UNI

Tags: mysql

This is my query and i cant correct.

```
 SELECT a.pack_id
 FROM (
      SELECT pl.pack_id
      FROM tbl_metals_list ml
      LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl ON ml.pack_id = pl.pack_id
      WHERE ml.sale_agent_id = '3' AND pl.current_tab='metals') a
 UNION(
      SELECT pl.pack_id
      FROM tbl_refining tr
      LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl ON tr.pack_id = pl.pack_id
      WHERE tr.sale_agent_id ='3' AND pl.current_tab = 'refining') b
```

Comment: You can't correct what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    a.pack_id 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        pl.pack_id 
    FROM 
        tbl_metals_list ml 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl 
        ON ml.pack_id = pl.pack_id 
    WHERE 
        ml.sale_agent_id = '3' 
        AND pl.current_tab='metals' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        pl.pack_id 
    FROM 
        tbl_refining tr 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl 
        ON tr.pack_id = pl.pack_id 
    WHERE 
        tr.sale_agent_id ='3' 
        AND pl.current_tab = 'refining' 
) a
```

**UPDATE:**

```
SELECT 
    a.pack_id ,
    d.company_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        pl.pack_id 
    FROM 
        tbl_metals_list ml 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl 
        ON ml.pack_id = pl.pack_id 
    WHERE 
        ml.sale_agent_id = '3' 
        AND pl.current_tab='metals' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        pl.pack_id 
    FROM 
        tbl_pack_list pl
    LEFT JOIN  tbl_refining tr 
        ON tr.pack_id = pl.pack_id 
    WHERE 
        tr.sale_agent_id ='3' 
        AND pl.current_tab = 'refining' 
) a 
INNER JOIN tbl_pack_list_details d
    ON a.pack_id = d.pack_id
```

Comment: Stephan,now i want join a new query with this original query SELECT pack_trans_id,pack_sent_date FROM tbl_pack_list WHERE pack_id='".$array['pack_id']."'

Comment: join them based on what conditions? pack_id?

Comment: i want to join this based on this pack_id

Comment: so just to get the picture straight you want to join the results from the query i posted with the query `SELECT pack_trans_id,pack_sent_date FROM tbl_pack_list WHERE pack_id='".$array['pack_id']."'` using pack_id?

Comment: first i need you to answer my previous question

Comment: yes,Stephan,i am trying to do this in a single query

Comment: try the updated query

Comment: Stephen,but problem is if i want to join new table in single query,then possible? how do i do this like  select company_name from tbl_pack_list_details where pack_id = '".$array['pack_id']."'

Comment: i do not understand what with what you want to join...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30415/discussion-between-stephan-and-user1987095)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT pl.pack_id 
FROM tbl_metals_list ml 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl ON ml.pack_id = pl.pack_id 
WHERE ml.sale_agent_id = '3' 
  AND pl.current_tab   = 'metals' 
UNION
SELECT pl.pack_id 
FROM tbl_refining tr 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pack_list pl ON tr.pack_id = pl.pack_id 
WHERE tr.sale_agent_id = '3' 
  AND pl.current_tab   = 'refining'
```